# Zend Session TypeError

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I'm trying to handle php sessions using the zendframework/zend-session (v.2.8) library. The problem is, I cannot start the session because of an internal TypeError in the zend-session library. Is this a bug or how can I fix my code to make it work?

```
<?php

use Zend\Session\Config\StandardConfig;
use Zend\Session\Container as SessionContainer;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;
use Zend\Session\Storage\SessionStorage;
use Zend\Session\Storage\ArrayStorage;

$config = new StandardConfig();
$config->setOptions([
    'remember_me_seconds' => 3600,
    'name' => 'app', 
    'use_cookies' => true,
    'cookie_httponly' => true,
]);

$manager = new SessionManager($config);
$manager->setStorage(new SessionStorage());

// Start session
$session = new SessionContainer('Default', $manager); // <--- Error
```

Error message:

```
Details

Type: TypeError
Message: Argument 1 passed to Zend\Stdlib\ArrayUtils::merge() must be of the type array, object given, called in C:\<path>\vendor\zendframework\zend-session\src\SessionManager.php on line 136
File: C:\<path>\vendor\zendframework\zend-stdlib\src\ArrayUtils.php
Line: 269
```

Edit: It looks like a bug in SessionManager.php

```
if ($oldSessionData instanceof \Traversable
    || (! empty($oldSessionData) && is_array($oldSessionData))
) {
    // $oldSessionData is not an array, it's an Zend\Session\Storage\SessionStorage
    $_SESSION = ArrayUtils::merge($oldSessionData, $_SESSION, true); // <--- TypeError.
}
```

Edit: This bug is resolved with the 2.8.1 release.